# How to install Panucci?

Tags: software-installation, audio-player, gpodder

I am completely new to both Linux/GNU and Ubuntu, and I might be incredibly dense, but I have not been able to download and install Panucci audio player for gPodder. I tried cloning the GitHub repository (https://github.com/gpodder/panucci) and running the *setup.py*-file but to no avail. I then tried downloading the *.install*-file from this page http://maemo.org/downloads/product/Maemo5/panucci/, but I couldn't find out how to run it.

The solution is probably very simple, but I have spent way too much time trying to find it out.

Edit:
This is the result of trying to use *make install*

```
(base) konki@HP-Spectre-x360:~/panucci$ make
make: 'data/panucci.service' is up to date.
(base) konki@HP-Spectre-x360:~/panucci$ sudo make install
[sudo] password for konki: 
for langfile in data/po/*.po; do \
  mo_dir="data/locale/`basename ${langfile} .po`/LC_MESSAGES/"; \
  mkdir -p ${mo_dir}; \
  msgfmt ${langfile} -o ${mo_dir}/panucci.mo; \
done
/bin/sh: 4: msgfmt: not found
/bin/sh: 4: msgfmt: not found
/bin/sh: 4: msgfmt: not found
/bin/sh: 4: msgfmt: not found
/bin/sh: 4: msgfmt: not found
/bin/sh: 4: msgfmt: not found
make: *** [makefile:43: mo] Error 127
```

Edit 2:
Turned out python wasn't installed correctly, and I apparently needed to install *gettext*. This is what I did, and it compiled:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python
$ sudo apt-get install gettext
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

This had to be done in the terminal opened from within the directory, not in one opened with "Ctrl+Alt+T". I did this by right-clicking an empty space in the directory and pressing "Open in Terminal".

My apparently last problem is now that the program won't launch. When pressing the icon in the GUI it simply does nothing, and when trying to run the executable from `/usr/bin` it yields this:

```
(base) konki@HP-Spectre-x360:~$ sudo '/usr/bin/panucci' 
[sudo] password for konki: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/panucci", line 64, in <module>
    from panucci import main
ImportError: No module named panucci
```

It appears the python executable tries to import a module named `panucci` which does not exist.

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using? The app seem to have updated 9 years ago and depends on Python 2. Did you get any error while running `setup.py`?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I think you are correct that the python version might be the problem. I got some Type Error when trying to run setup.py when it tried to print using the Python 2 syntax for printing. I tried changing all the prints to the new syntax and the code ran, but it printed an error saying a file was missing in a directory and asked me to use "make install" instead, and I don't know how I would go about doing that. I tried """make setup.py install""", but that probably isn't the right syntax anyway.

Comment: just type 'make', then 'sudo make install'. it compiled immediately, I am also running on Ubuntu 20.04 and I used the download from github.